# Tcp Server deixa de "responder"

Tags: c#, winforms, socket, tcp

É o seguinte eu tenho andado a ver 2 tutorial de como fazer um tcp [Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXFso7xSSWk) e um tcp [Client](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NanjpGKC2js).
Eu tive a seguir tudo passo passo mas por alguma razão quando inicio o server ele deixa de responder, mas quando o client connecta ele da um update mostra e numa textbox "New Message: Hello From Client". Depois disso só se eu connectar outra vez é que ele volta a responder mas logo a seguir ele deixa de responder. Isto só aconteçe com o server.

```
 private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TcpServerRun();
        Thread tcpserverRunThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TcpServerRun));

    }

    private void TcpServerRun()
    {
        TcpListener tcplistener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Convert.ToInt32(TxtBoxPort.Text));
        tcplistener.Start();
        updateUI("listening");

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = tcplistener.AcceptTcpClient();
            updateUI("Connected");
            Thread tcpHandlerThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(tcpHandler));
            tcpHandlerThread.Start(client);
        }
    }
    private void tcpHandler(object client)
    {
        TcpClient mClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream stream = mClient.GetStream();
        byte[] messagem = new byte[1024];
        stream.Read(messagem, 0, messagem.Length);
        updateUI("New Message: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(messagem));
        stream.Close();
        mClient.Close();
    }

    private void updateUI(string s)
    {
        Func<int> del = delegate()
        {
            TxtBoxLog.AppendText(s + System.Environment.NewLine);
            return 0;
        };
        Invoke(del);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu servidor fica sem responder pois está escutando/aguardando uma nova conexão. Este método é chamado Blocking Mode das sockets.

Caso você precise efetuar alguma tarefa enquanto o servidor escuta por uma nova conexão existem duas maneiras de cumprir esta tarefa:

1) Criar uma thread separada para escutar por conexões. Desta forma a thread principal fica liberada para efetuar outras tarefas enquanto a thread de escuta fica parada em "tcplistener.AcceptTcpClient()".

2) Existe a possibilidade de você programar uma socket em modo "Non-Blocking", desta forma nenhuma chamada a API de Sockets bloqueia a sua aplicação, mas é necessário tratar os retornos para identificar quando realmente há uma conexão disponível. É a forma mais utilizada em servidores TCP, mas a sua implementação mudaria bastante em relação com o que está feito hoje.

Espero ter conseguido ajudar.